# Git: Create a remote branch that tracks remote master

Tags: git, branch

I am afraid this has been answered already somewhere but i can't find it.

So i want to create a remote branch "newfeature1" that tracks the remote master.
I would expect that if i track the master and the newfeature1 branch in my local repository
that i could change something in master, commit and push, then switch to the newfeature1 branch do a git pull and would get that change there as well. But that doesn't work.

Here's what i tried:

Create remote branch
`git push origin origin:refs/heads/newfeature1`

Force it to track remote master
`git branch --track origin/newfeature1 origin/master`

Track remote branch locally
`git checkout --track origin/webkit`

Switch to local master (that tracks the remote master):
`git checkout master`

Modify some files and `git commit -am "test" && git push`

Switch to newfeature1 branch `git checkout newfeature1`

Pull from remote `git pull`

I would have expected to get the changes i did in the master branch here but i guess the remote branch does not automatically update from master even so it is tracking it.

Any hints on how to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have remote branches tracking other remote branches. You can only track a remote branch with a local branch. I think you have gotten some things backwards. When you commit to your local master and push those changes, you already have those changes in your local master, there is no need to track those changes from another branch. If you want those changes made to master to be in your local branch newfeature1, just checkout that branch and merge master

```
git checkout newfeature1
git merge master
```

There is no need to push up your newfeature1 to the remote repository, unless you actually want to share that branch when collaborating with other developers. Keep it local.

Comment: Thanks i was really trying to do it the other way around. But you are right doing the merge locally works just fine.